# Angular Function Result not displaying in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So i recently learned Angular. For some reason when ever I pull data using {{some.data.goes.here}} in the HTML. The result of this pull does not reflect in the DOM.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('AppController', function() {

    this.product = shirts;

  });

  var shirts = [{
      name: 'BlackShirt',
      price: 100,
    }

  ];

})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <div class="w3-card-2 w3-border content-panels">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center">
      <p>{{product.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to where the issue lies. Please help.
I have tried using the following.

```
{{product.name}}
{{shirts.name}}
{{product.shirts.name}}
{{shirts.product.name}}
{{app.product.name}}
{{app.shirts.name}}
```

I dont know what to try anymore. My result arent displaying.

Comment: The Angular is function in the DOM. I have tried debuggin with some math expressions and those work fine. im just having an issue with my Array of data

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: I dont see your answer. Think it was deleted

Comment: Yea I removed it because I thought I understood your problem, but I was mistaken so my answer no longer applies : /

Comment: LOL @vincecampanale your funny.

Comment: Just tried useing MOZ - still a blank DOM

Comment: You're mixing up angularjs and angular

Comment: There are no console Errors

Comment: @Z.Bagley Please explain - I alos have another app that works fine. And i made it the same way.

Comment: I literally copied a functional app. Change the array data. Now its not working.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant for your tag. AngularJS (1.x) is what you're using. You tagged it Angular (2+). I don't use AngularJS at all, so the new tag might get you better help. gl

Comment: That must been a mistake. I didnt look at the tag description when choosing it sorry. I will update it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it is working now.

I am using this:
     {{product.name}}

Wierd how it's working now.

Thanks though.